# A bounded operator satisfies $\|Tx\|\leq\|T\| \|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove that if $T$ is a bounded linear operator, from $X$ to $Y$, then for each $x\in X $ we must have  $\|Tx\|\leq\|T\| \|x\|$.

Let's take some nonzero $x\in X$ . Then $\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} \leq \sup_x \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} $. But this supremum is the definition of $\|T\|$ so we must have that $\|Tx\| \leq \|T\| \|x\|$. I'm not sure if I can take the sup as I did, and with $x$ changing in the denominator, and in the image, that it will be necessarily bigger or equal to the right hand side.

Comment: Notice the visual difference between $||a|| ||b||$, coded as ||a|| ||b||, and $\|a\| \|b\|$, coded as \|a\| \|b\|.  In the latter method, which is standard usage, there is no need to manually add extra spacing as you did.  I edited your question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the definition of $\|T\|$ to be $\|T\| = \sup\left\{\dfrac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X \right\}$, then it is a triviality that $\|Tx\| \le \|T\|\|x\|$ for every $x\in X$.

But sometimes the definition is taken to be $\|T\| = \sup\left\{\dfrac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : \|x\|\le 1 \right\}$ or $\|T\| = \sup\left\{\dfrac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : \|x\|\ = 1 \right\}$.  In those cases there's just a bit more work.  You can write

$$
\|Tx\| = \left\| \|x\| T\left( \frac x {\|x\|} \right) \right\| = \|x\| \left\| T \frac x {\|x\|} \right\| \le \|x\| \|T\| \left\| \frac x {\|x\|}\right\| = \|x\|\|T\| \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|} = \|x\|\|T\|.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is valid. You are uncertain about the use of the same letter $x$ on both sides... it's not wrong, since on the right $x$ is a dummy variable. But if you want to avoid this repetition, write

$$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} \leq \sup_{y\ne0} \frac{\|Ty\|}{\|y\|} = \|T\|$$

You may also want to add that for $x=0$ the inequality holds because $Tx=0$.